# Adobe Premier Pro CS6 crashes at startup

Tags: boot, crash, adobe-premiere

I installed Adobe Premier Pro CS6 on Macbook Pro running 10.6.8 and keep getting error message (see screenshot). I have installed several other CS6 apps and they all worked, or worked after installing updates. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or know a solution? I have seen many reports of crashes once running but none upon startup.[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: have you tried fixing the permissions on your home folder?

Comment: @BroScience, I repaired permissions but still get same error message.

Comment: by chance are you also using VMWare Fusion? I have the same problem and suspect Fusion has changed the folder permissions, making me hesitant to change them back for fear of breaking Fusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  My Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 crashed, displaying a message that Adobe Premiere stopped working.

After checking all other things, I realized it was a graphics card issue. I am using a Dell laptop with AMD graphics card.  What fixed it for me:

First step, install Dell video drivers from their site and also install AMD autodetect, which detects your driver and downloads required updates. You need both Dell and AMD drivers.

Once it is done, at the startup you can see the GFX icon there change performance settings from balanced to high quality.